# Sum to end of row in Org Mode Spreadsheet

Tags: org-mode

I've tried both of the following formulas:

```
=vsum($4..$>)
=vsum(@0$4..@0$>)
```

It seems like either of these should work.

Comment: Column and row numbering in Org tables starts at 1. I've just tried your second example and it worked for me (with 0 changed to 1).

Comment: @0 means the current row, if I'm not mistaken. Does the first example work for you?

Comment: Nope, current row would be `@#` (current column is `$#`). The first example does work, but I'm not sure if it's intended to work that way.

Answer (score 4):

```
|    |   |   |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
|    |   |   |  8 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 |
|----+---+---+----+----+----+----+----|
| 60 |   |   | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 |
#+TBLFM: @3$1=vsum(@2$4..@2$>)
#+TBLFM: @3$1=vsum($4..$>)
```

Here's the table I tested with. If you switch formulas (move the one in the second row to the first row) and re-evaluate, you will get 90, which seems to imply that unless you specify the row, `vsum` will result in the sum of the last row.